# Custom ListBox with transparent backcolor issue

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, custom-controls, transparent

I created a custom multiline ListBox control inherited from ListBox. In the form, the ListBox position is above a WPF rounded and transparent panel hosted in an ElementHost. Now, what I want, is that ListBox backcolor to be transparent. Obviously, this is not allowed in Winforms, a ListBox cant be transparent. Then, I have tried some things, but there is always an issue.

What I want to achieve is this:

[image]

As you can see, this works perfectly, but actually I´m having two problems.

The first I get is when I select an item. The letters became pretty ugly. Just compare the next image with the first one. You can see all of them looks ugly because all of them were selected.

[image]

The second problem I have, is when I scroll down/up the ListBox. The transparent color just dissapears and I get a black color.

[image]

I remember getting this issue with a scrollable panel in a Form. The panel was transparent and the way to solve it was to call Invalidate() method in the panel Scroll event. But I don´t have that event in the ListBox.

Also, I want to hide the scrollbar but to be scrollable.

I attach the CustomListBox code so you can see what I have done. You are free to take it if you want a simple multiline ListBox too.

Just in case, the way that I used to set the ListBox to transparent, was by overriding CreateParams.

public class MultiLineListBox : System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
    {
        public MultiLineListBox()
        {
            this.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
            this.ScrollAlwaysVisible = true;
        }

```
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x20; // WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
            return cp;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMeasureItem(MeasureItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Site!=null)
            return;
        if(e.Index > -1)
        {
            string s = Items[e.Index].ToString();
            SizeF sf = e.Graphics.MeasureString(s,Font,Width);
            int htex = (e.Index==0) ? 15 : 10;
            e.ItemHeight = (int)sf.Height + htex;           
            e.ItemWidth = Width;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Site!=null)
            return;
        if(e.Index > -1)
        {
            string s = Items[e.Index].ToString();                           

            if((e.State & DrawItemState.Focus)==0)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(s,Font,new SolidBrush(Color.White),e.Bounds);             
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 26, 36, 41)),e.Bounds);                
            }
            else
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 185, 57)), e.Bounds);
                //e.Graphics.DrawString(s,Font,new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 161, 47)),e.Bounds);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Oh, I almost forget. I tried overriding the OnPaintBackGround(), it worked by setting SetStyle to userPaint. But it was even more undesirable, because I was not just having the same problems as the other solution, but also the text was not showed, so, I sticked to the first solution.

Hope somebody can help me out!

Comment: winforms doesn't support any of that. You're already using `ElementHost`, why not just create a WPF ListBox with a proper `ItemTemplate` and a nice `Style` with transparencies?... you need 0 lines of C# code and some 10 to 20 lines of XAML in order to do that in WPF.

Comment: @HighCore is it possible to do many things in Winforms. It´s just more complicated. I know I can do this on WPF easier, but I dont know much about it. The listbox will have a contextmenu for every item. All that requirements made me to stay away from WPF.

Comment: a `ContextMenu` is just a graphical representation of a `List<ICommand>`. I don't see how that could be complicated. Everything is easier in WPF, and also performs better. When you finish this winforms app you'll realize its unusable because of bad performance, and will have to re-do it entirely in WPF anyways.

Comment: Also, my idea of `"technology or framework ABC supports XYZ"`, is that you can achieve XYZ using ABC in a normal amount of time without resorting to a bunch of HACKS (such as having to call unmanaged code just to do some UI-related stuff). Therefore, winforms doesn't support any of these things. IMO.

Comment: @HighCore Winform is slow, it has nothing to do with Interop with WPF. As I told you, I know little of WPF. Thats why I´m using Winforms. Because I know about it. The app is almost finished. I cant migrate all of it to a technology I dont master.

Comment: I think it is important to point out here that WinForms and WPF are two very different technologies. WinForms is drawn using GDI/GDI+. WPF is a new mechanism for augmenting UI, and is based on DirectX. In fact, Windows (as of Windows Vista) uses DirectX for the entire desktop. The desktop is now in fact, 2 triangles, connected along the hypotenues. I don't think it's fair to say that WinForms relies on "hacks", its just that it was grown too large to accommodate today's UI requirements. That being said, if you learn the API, you can still create some awesome WinForms controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this...

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
{
    IntPtr hdc = pevent.Graphics.GetHdc();
    Rectangle rect = this.ClientRectangle;
    NativeMethods.DrawThemeParentBackground(this.Handle, hdc, ref rect);
    pevent.Graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
}


internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("uxtheme", ExactSpelling = true)]
    public extern static Int32 DrawThemeParentBackground(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hdc, ref Rectangle pRect);
}
```

Its worked for me when I've needed to paint a transparent background color for a control that did not support it. I used it with a TabControl.

Comment: Nice.. have to resort to WinAPI to do something equivalent to `<ListBox Background="Transparent"/>` in WPF.

Comment: I will try this in some minutes. Just in case, does this works properly when scrolling?

Comment: @Andres do you still want a WPF solution? I can help you create the `ItemTemplate`, the `ViewModel` with its `Command`s to use as `ContextMenu`, and the `ListBox` style if you want.

Comment: @HighCore Thank you, but I think the app will be easier to mantain if I stay with one technology. I just used WPF for good looking controls because I knew about that technology just some months ago. If this cannot be achieved in wirforms I will just leave the background black.

Comment: @Andres Okay. But WPF is not just about good looking controls. Its a really powerful UI framework that supports things such as DataBinding, Control Templating, Data Templating, Styles, Animations, and allows for a really unique separation of concerns between UI and application logic never imagined with previous technologies. WPF helps you write clean, easy code, that manipulates your own data objects and classes instead of complex UI classes, while keeping away from hacks and WinAPIs to do any UI-related stuff. I suggest you consider it for all new projects, as a replacement of winforms.

Comment: @HighCore Yes, I do consider to learn it. Actually I really want to, I saw all that good things you just told me, but this project is almost finished and its draining all my time right now.

Comment: @Andres, I think you need to keep updating the control when scrolling on order for it to work properly. If this is a WinForms control, you may want to consider using the SetStyle method to improve visual performance while scrolling.

Comment: Yes, I set it like that. But still. I also tried with the Invalidate(). But same. I guess the only "easy" way, would be to have only one color or to use gradient backgrounds in every item.

Comment: @HighCore, what is the problem with resorting to WinAPI? Most of .NET's underlying code relies on the WinAPI, so programming it yourself is nothing new. The only difference is that with WPF, Microsoft have smoothed over all of the holes in the WinForms API (thus creating WPF). Eventually, you will probably find a load of "hacks" in WPF, and Microsoft will have to brainstorm a new UI idea (WPFx??) to handle all of the holes in WPF. it's the nature of progession on the software world.

Comment: @Andres, did you set (ControlStyles) UserPaint, AllPaintingInWmPaint, ResizeRedraw, and OptimizedDoubleBuffer? - This is what I usually do. Then I have a function which does: Invalidate(this.ClientRectangle); Update(); - You must call update explicitly if you want to force a redraw

Comment: @series0ne I did not used all that methods. Do you have a code example of them? Will I have a strange effect when I scroll(redraw lag)?

Comment: @Andres UserPaint, AllPaintInWmPaint, ResizeRedraw and OptimizedDoubleBuffer are members of the ControlStyles enumeration. you set them with SetStyle(), usually in your constructor / initialization method, before you start drawing anything. As for Invalidate(this.ClientRectangle); Update(); <-- these two methods should be called whenever you need to update the control surface. i.e. when scrolling, resizing, etc.

Comment: Thanks but I´m having that horrible effect when scrolling :S

Comment: @Andres, yes I know what you mean. I believe the issue is caused because the parent background is not being redrawn when the control is redrawn. What you may need to do is work out the coordinates of the control is relation to the parent, invalidate that rectangle on the parent, and redraw that as well.

Comment: Thanks @series0ne I think this is the way to go. But I it is too tedious to code all that for just a transparent listBox with a scrollbar. I finally managed to use one backcolor very similar to the background. So it looks pretty anyways. I ll select this as an answer to the question.

Comment: @Andres, cool. The problem I was trying to solve using this approach was: Draw a textured window, like Visual Studio 2010, and then draw a custom drawn TabControl over the top of that. Since TabControl does not support transparent backgrounds I had to use this to paint the textured background onto the TabControl. It was a bit glitchy to start with, but eventually managed to smooth out all of the bugs...looks sweet now (basically I remade the VS2010 UI using WinForms controls) :-)