# How to make transparent background to ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, backcolor

I have a c# WinForms application with a picture in the background. I put a ListBox to the window and I would like to change the `BackColor` to transparent to my ListBox. But the ListBox doesn't support transparent `BackColor`. What can I do for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom ListBox with transparent backcolor issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207186/custom-listbox-with-transparent-backcolor-issue)

Comment: Imo, th best course of action is to give up on the idea. Maybe, if the listbox has only limited functionality you can fake it with labels or flat buttons, maybe sitting in a panel..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do should be something like:

Say, we want to create a transparent list box named `TansparentListBox`. So we need to derive a new class from the `ListBox` control, set some control styles to make it double buffered, prevent painting the background, and to say that we will do the painting ourselves:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;

[ToolboxBitmap(typeof(ListBox)),
    DesignerCategory("")]
public class TransparentListBox : ListBox
{

    public TransparentListBox() : base()
    {
        SetStyle(
            ControlStyles.Opaque |
            ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
            ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw |
            ControlStyles.UserPaint |
            ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    }
    //...
```

Now we need to override both the `OnPaint` and `OnDrawItem` events to do the drawing. The [DrawThemeParentBackground](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-drawthemeparentbackground) function is required to copy the parent's background, just the region of our control. Also we have a new member, the `SelectionBackColor` property, the background color of the selected items:

```cs
    //...
    public Color SelectionBackColor { get; set; } = Color.DarkOrange;

    [DllImport("uxtheme", ExactSpelling = true)]
    private extern static int DrawThemeParentBackground(
        IntPtr hWnd, 
        IntPtr hdc, 
        ref Rectangle pRect
        );

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var g = e.Graphics;
        var rec = ClientRectangle;

        IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc();
        DrawThemeParentBackground(this.Handle, hdc, ref rec);
        g.ReleaseHdc(hdc);

        using (Region reg = new Region(e.ClipRectangle))
        {
            if (Items.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    rec = GetItemRectangle(i);

                    if (e.ClipRectangle.IntersectsWith(rec))
                    {
                        if ((SelectionMode == SelectionMode.One && SelectedIndex == i) ||
                            (SelectionMode == SelectionMode.MultiSimple && SelectedIndices.Contains(i)) ||
                            (SelectionMode == SelectionMode.MultiExtended && SelectedIndices.Contains(i)))
                            OnDrawItem(new DrawItemEventArgs(g, Font, rec, i, DrawItemState.Selected, ForeColor, BackColor));
                        else
                            OnDrawItem(new DrawItemEventArgs(g, Font, rec, i, DrawItemState.Default, ForeColor, BackColor));

                        reg.Complement(rec);
                    }
                }
            }
        }            
    }

    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Index < 0) return;

        var rec = e.Bounds;
        var g = e.Graphics;

        g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;

        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
            using (SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(SelectionBackColor))
                g.FillRectangle(sb, rec);

        using (SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(ForeColor))
        using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat { Alignment = StringAlignment.Near, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center })
            g.DrawString(GetItemText(Items[e.Index]), Font, sb, rec, sf);
    }
    //...
```

The hard part is done. To finish up, the drawing should be refreshed on occurrence of certain events, otherwise it will be a visual chaos:

```cs
    //...
    protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseWheel(e);
        Invalidate();
    }
    //...
```

Also, a refresh is required when using both, the vertical and horizontal scroll bars. Doing that is possible by overriding the `WndProc` since the ListBox control does not have any scroll events.

```cs
    //...
    private const int WM_KILLFOCUS  = 0x8;
    private const int WM_VSCROLL    = 0x115;
    private const int WM_HSCROLL    = 0x114;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg != WM_KILLFOCUS && 
            (m.Msg == WM_HSCROLL || m.Msg == WM_VSCROLL))
            Invalidate();
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

That's it. Puzzle up, rebuild and try.

[image: TransparentListBox]

Comment: Thank you very much for this, how we can control transparency?

Comment: no namespace? nooooooooooo